# What would you call a pleading before a judge or God

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there a noun or adjective for the following or similar:

- a pleading before a judge for clemency
- a prayer before God begging for mercy

Is there a better word than "begging", "pleading", "petitioning", etc.?

Comment: Better for what?  You haven't told us why "begging", "pleading", "petitioning", etc. aren't acceptable.  What are you trying to explain that those words don't explain?

Comment: Not 'plead' but 'plea'. 'Plea' is the noun.

Comment: Ineffective? *cough*

Comment: As @Mitch suggests, the *noun* "pleading" tends to be used to refer to an event (eg, a court hearing), while "plea" refers to the supplication itself ("a plea for justice").

Comment: _To seek clemency/seeking [clemency](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/clemency)_ is often used. But not as a noun(seeking) recently. As others have said, the _plea_. You _make a plea for it to s.o_ or _you seek it from s.o_, that I know.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> Judge or God, clemency or mercy..

**Supplication**, a noun, can logically be applied to any situation in which you **plead to someone in power** for help or a favor.

**Supplication**:  comes from the Latin verb [supplicare](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=supplication), which means "to plead humbly."
(etymonline.com)

> **[Supplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supplication)** (also known as petitioning) is a form of prayer, wherein
>   one party humbly or earnestly asks another party to provide something,
>   either for the party who is doing the supplicating (e.g., "Please
>   spare my life.") or on behalf of someone else (e.g., "Please spare my
>   child's life.").
>   (wiki)

Comment: +1 for a great word but please include your source in case your link goes stale. :-)

Comment: @KristinaLopez - what does that mean, "link goes stale"? Stops working? Why does that happen?

Comment: @LittleEva - The reference to a link going stale (a.k.a. 'going dead' or succumbing to 'link rot') pertains to the fact that the URL it consists of is no longer pointing to the desired page (or even to any page at all). See [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).

Comment: +1 @Erik Kowal - so it's been removed or the addy has changed?

Comment: @LittleEva - Exactly so, as the article describes.

Comment: @LittleEva - [**This article**](http://www.slate.com/articles/technology/technology/2009/10/how_geocities_invented_the_internet.html) on the history of ***GeoCities*** should be highly informative on the issue of why it is important to avoid link rot. Even the biggest websites can die. In fact [here is a different link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120114052415/http://www.slate.com/articles/technology/technology/2009/10/how_geocities_invented_the_internet.html) to the same article in case the first one dies.

Comment: Since the OP mentioned prayer: *do not be anxious about anything, but in everything by prayer and **supplication** with thanksgiving let your requests be made known to God.* - Philippians 4:6 ESV

Answer (score 10):

*Prayer* may be best because it is actually a legal term of art.  E.g., I'm looking at a court order that reads "... it is hereby ORDERED and DECREED that the **prayer** of the Petition is DENIED...."

Comment: +1 yes, it's commonly encountered in legal writing and often heard in the court room.

Comment: As in "pray tell," pray is another way of saying "please" (I think).

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps *[entreaty](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/entreaty)*

> An earnest or humble request:
>   *the king turned a deaf ear to his entreaties*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Answer (score 7):

The noun [**imploration**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/imploration) might be suitable to your needs.

> **An act of begging someone to do something**:
> *earnest implorations for divine forgiveness and mercy*

From the verb *[implore](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Implore&searchmode=none)* Etymonline tells us

> v.
> c.1500, from Middle French *implorer* and directly from Latin *implorare* "call for help, *beseech*," originally "invoke with weeping," from assimilated form of ***in***- "on, upon" *+ plorare* "to weep, cry out." Related: *Implored ; imploring ; imploringly.*

Answer (score 1):

In the English criminal courts the defence, between conviction and sentencing, may make **a plea in mitigation**.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of religion I would use the word "prostrate" or "prostration". This is when you kneel down with your body flat before a God or religious icon. I have used the word in non religious instances too but this may not be correct.

Comment: I'd be very surprised to see a defendant prostrate in court...

Comment: Only if it's from heat stroke.